# Sorting file content using String value in a certain sequence

Tags: bash, sorting

I had a jumbled up file content as follows:

```
13,13,GAME_FINISH,
1,1,GAME_START,
1,1,GROUP_FINISH,
17,17,WAGER,200.00
2,2,GAME_FINISH,
2,2,GAME_START,
22,22,GAME_WIN,290.00
2,2,GROUP_FINISH,
32,32,WAGER,200.00
3,3,GAME_FINISH,
3,3,GAME_START,
.... more lines
```

I sorted it and currently hold the file content in following format:

```
1,1,GAME_FINISH,
1,1,GAME_START,
1,1,GROUP_FINISH,
1,1,WAGER,200.00
2,2,GAME_FINISH,
2,2,GAME_START,
2,2,GAME_WIN,290.00
2,2,GROUP_FINISH,
2,2,WAGER,200.00
3,3,GAME_FINISH,
3,3,GAME_START,
3,3,GROUP_FINISH,
3,3,WAGER,200.00
... more lines
```

But how can I sort it better to obtain following format? 3rd and 4th line may not always exist.

```
1,1,WAGER,200.00
1,1,GAME_START,
1,1,GAME_WIN,500.00
1,1,BONUS_WIN_1,1100.00
1,1,GAME_FINISH,
1,1,GROUP_FINISH,
2,2, more lines...
```

For the initial sort, I used

```
sort -t, -g -k2 nameofunsortedfile.csv >> sortedfile.csv
```

Added Information:

I want to sort it in this order - Wager, game start, game win, bonus win, game finish, group finish. My current sorted is not in this order. Game win and bonus win may not always be present.

The order I am expecting is not dictionary but also not random. Every number always has a wager, start, game_finish group_finish sequence. game_win, game_bonus are optional. Looking for a way to example target 1,1 sort in the expected sequence mentioned, move on to 2,2 do the same and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this with standard UNIX utilities is probably to add an additional field to each line, which encodes the type of record in a way that sorts into the order you want.

```
declare -A mapping=( ["WAGER"]=1 ["GAME_START"]=2 ["GAME_WIN"]=3 ["BONUS_WIN"]=4 ["GAME_FINISH"]=5 ["GROUP_FINISH"]=6 )
cut -d, -f3 filename.txt | while read; do echo ${mapping["$REPLY"]}; done | paste -d, - filename.txt | sort | sort -s -t, -n -k 2,3 | cut -d, -f 2-
```

The `declare` statement declares a mapping that allows you to look up the ordering of each record type. The specific values (`1`, `2`, etc.) don't matter as long as they sort into the order you want; you could use letters or words if you prefer.

Then the next line consists of the following commands:

- `cut -d, -f3 filename.txt` extracts the thing you want to sort by (`WAGER` or whatever)
- `while read; do echo ${mapping["$REPLY"]}; done` takes each value (`WAGER` etc.) and replaces it with its corresponding sortable value from the associative array `mapping`
- `paste -d, - filename.txt` sticks those values back on to the start of each line from `filename.txt`
- `sort | sort -s -t, -n -k 2,3` has the effect of sorting by field 2, then field 3, then field 1 (the one we added). If `sort` could use three fields as keys, we could do this in a single `sort` command, but it only accepts up to two fields to sort by.
- `cut -d, -f 2-` strips off the added field, leaving you with your original records, but in sorted order

Comment: Works great! Just made a slight adjustment to text from GROUP_WIN to GAME_FINISH. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @kar Ah, yes, that was a typo on my part. Sorry!.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $i = 1;
my %order = map { $_ => $i++ }
            qw( WAGER GAME_START GAME_WIN BONUS_WIN GAME_FINISH GROUP_FINISH );

chomp( my @lines = <> );
say join ',', @$_ for sort {
    $a->[0] <=> $b->[0]
    || $order{ $a->[2] } <=> $order{ $b->[2] }
} map [ split /,/ ], @lines;
```

The [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) block tells Perl to first sort by the first column, and if the values are the same, use the "order" corresponding to the third one.

Comment: Limited Perl knowledge. Understand what you mean in the explanation. Will test it out. Thanks.